# Rendering array of objects having default values, declared using useState is not working while displaying in table

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I have one **users** array of objects declared using useState as show below:

```
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([
    {
      prn: 12,
      name: "Shrut",
      gender: "M",
      mobile: 1234567890,
      dept: "CSE",
      year: "First",
      sem: "Second"
    },
    {
      prn: 13,
      name: "Shrutika",
      gender: "M",
      mobile: 1234567890,
      dept: "CSE",
      year: "First",
      sem: "Second"
    }
  ]);
```

And I am trying to display this value using map inside table but getting error that **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading prn)**

```
<tbody>
    {     
        users.map((obj, index) => {

            return (
                <tr key={index}>
                    <td>{obj.prn}</td>
                    <td>{obj.name}</td>
                    <td>{obj.gender}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you never change this state? https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-lamarr-r5qguo?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I am changing it. Actually there are so many states. I thought some problem here that's why posted this much code.

Comment: So it's not default anymore

Comment: Can you tell me how can I make it to work

Comment: I have no idea, there are many ways of writing a code and I have no idea what your look like. You have to provide the entire component at least so we can find the issue,

Comment: @KonradLinkowski One more thing I noticed. When I displayed only one row with 0 index, it displayed the data. But when I removed it to use map it's giving this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247102/discussion-between-shrutika-subhash-dorugade-and-konrad-linkowski).

Comment: Hey @KonradLinkowski, Can you once check this. Here is the complete code
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-cloud-17kpy4?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in `onDeleteSubmit`

You used `map` but you wanted to use `filter`

```
const onDeleteSubmit = (id) => {
    var updatedUsers = users.filter((obj, index) => {
      if (index != id) {
        return obj;
      }
    });
    setUsers(updatedUsers);
  };
```

Your `users` array looked like this after this operation `(2) [Object, undefined]` which caused the error

Comment: I did that. But still my row data is not getting displayed. It only display headers

Comment: I have no idea why, but it's related to the `input`s in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this answer so that if in future anyone getting same error it might help you.
My half of the problem is solved by @Konrad Linkowski (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73269803/11712874)

After correcting above mistake, my type error resolved but still I was  not able to display data in **users**. Below was my code:

```
users.map((obj, index) => { 
    return (
        <tr key={index}>
            <td>{obj.name}</td>                 
            <td>
                // conditional rendering of select tag or actual value of 
                obj.dept
            </td>
            <td>
                {
                    changeElementsOnUpdate == index ?
                        <input type="button" value="Done" disabled={disableButton}
                            onClick={onUpdateSubmit(index)}
                         />
                    :
                        <input type="button" value="Update" disabled={disableButton}
                            onClick={setChangeElementsOnUpdate(index)}
                        />
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" value="Delete" disabled={disableButton}
                        onClick={onDeleteSubmit(index)}
                />
            </td>
        </tr>
    )
})
```

By playing with the code, I observed that I am calling useState functions onClick without using callback. And that's the reason of the entire mess.

So I changed all calls as shown in the below sample:

```
<td>
    <input type="button" value="Delete" disabled={disableButton}
        onClick={() => {
            onDeleteSubmit(index)
        }}
    />
</td>
```